# Why article are different, "to have the sniffles" and "to have a cold"

Tags: articles

As far as I know "the" is used something already mentioned.

Why do you use "to have **the** sniffels"?
I don't get why these two expressions use different articles.

Comment: I doubt there is a logical explanation for all the idioms in your own native language.  Why should English be any different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following are typical symptoms of **a** cold or **the** flu or **flu** (without any article)

> I have **a** sore throat
>   You have **a**  high fever
>   He has **a** runny nose
>   She has **a** bad cough
>
> We've got **a** bad cold
>   We've got bad **colds**
>   They've got **[the sniffles](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/the%20sniffles)**  (colloquial)
>   They've got [the sneezes](http://www.gigglepoetry.com/poem.aspx?PoemID=100&CategoryID=9) (colloquial)

*“I've got **a** sniffling nose”* is idiomatic, but not *I've got sniffles*, for some reason the definite article, *the*, is required. A bit like saying someone has ***the flu*** (although “I have flu” is also possible to say).

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think "a cold" is singular whereas "the sniffles" is plural even though it's regarding one thing--a head cold.  Plural nouns in English never take an indefinite article, but they can take a definite article.

I think this is what you were asking about.  I hope I've read it correctly.  Take care and good luck!